# regex: capture group and lookahead not working

Tags: regex, perl, sas

So I know regexes for a couple of years and recently dived into it again.
I have been google-en for hours and don't quite understand what is going wrong.
I would like to extract the housenumber suffix, from:

> StreetnameA 278
>   StreetnameB 36 A
>   StreetnameC 37

So that I will get the ouput:

> A

My solutions so far don't work (capture group & positive lookbehind):

1. `/\d+\s(\w+)/`
2. `/(?<=\d+\s)\w+/`

Am I misunderstanding the capture group and positive lookaround functions?

Comment: A lookbehind would look like `/(?<=\d+\s)\w+/`

Comment: you need to access the first capturing group in your first answer with a bit modification :- `\d+\s(\w)$`

Comment: See your [`\d+\s(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nA6zA3/1) in action. It captures what you need.

Comment: What is the language you are using? JS? C#? PHP? As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Comment: I use SAS, it uses Perl to parse

Comment: If i use \d+\s(\w+) , it will capture "36 A", while I only want "A"

Comment: use `$1` to access the first group

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it may raise an issue as lookbehind should be of zero width

Comment: The result is "StreetnameB", still not the "A" answer

Comment: sorry :- use `(?<=\d\s)\w+$`

Comment: thanks, i tried and added the dollar sign. But there's no match at all :(

Comment: ok then try :- `(?<=\d\s)\w+(?!\w)`

Comment: That works! Thanks! The key was in the quantifier +

Answer (score 1):

The following is

1. searching for a number (\d)
2. followed by one or more whitespaces (\s)+
3. at the end of the line ($)

(\w+) is the stuff that we're looking for. I.e. one or multiple word characters.

```
\d\s+(\w+)$
```

Then read the first group.

Comment: If i try this out in https://regex101.com/#python i don't get a match? "string = "StreetnameA 278
StreetnameB 36 A
StreetnameC 37"

Comment: @chuck_nl You have global and multi-line on? On the site you mention that's modifiers g and m.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements!

Comment: That helps! Now both solutions work, thank you!
p.s. multiline and global were on, i put it out now :)